# svn: generic failure

Tags: svn

I know this problem is asked multiple times around the globe, but I believe mine is a little different from the others.

The scenario is as follow:

> **Day1:** Installing an Ubuntu Server 10.04 on a cloud server with
>   Subversion 1.6.6 on a remote server.
>
> **Day2:** Importing the first project into svn through svn+ssh protocol.
>   Everything works fine to the end of the day.
>
> **Day3:** Trying to checkout the project on a different computer. Result:
>   *svn: generic failure*

In most of the reported cases of the same problem, it seems the problem is related to SASL but in my case it's disabled and I'm not using SASL. I've faced the same problem, not long ago, on a different server with CentOS installed.

As of the next step I logged into the remote server through SSH and tried to checkout the same project out of the repository using 'file:///' protocol. And it worked fine! It seems whatever  the problem is, it has something to do with the authentication protocol. But since the error prompt is minimal, I do not know where to start.

UPDATE: Switching from 'file:///' to 'svn+ssh://' works fine on the remote server as well.

UPDATE: Testing from a third computer, everything works fine there too and it seems it's just my local computer unable to checkout and/or commit the repository! Could it be some sort of firewall blocking issue?

Comment: After more than a day and a half searching for a resolution to this problem, this solved it for me. Many thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

svn needs your hostname routed to 127.0.0.1 (local)

if your hostname is not in

```
cat /etc/hosts
```

this will add your current hostname to it:

```
#(as root)
echo 127.0.0.1 `hostname`>> /etc/hosts
```

Answer (score 6):

Had issues with hostname being not resolved.
Fixed by adding hostname to 127.0.0.1 to /etc/hosts

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
~$ hostname
ubuntu
```

Edit file /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 ubuntu
```

Comment: be awre, that this would change the hostname of your server to "ubuntu"

Comment: Ok, now after Jacks edit it looks a bit better, but still: "ubuntu" is not always your servername, you have to add the hostname, that the command `hostname` will show to /etc/hosts